# ViewForAnnotation work in iPad 6.0 simulator but doesn't work in iPad 5.1 simulator

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I started to build an app with iOS6 that worked great, but then for reasons of force grater, I had to switch to IOS5. However, there is a map that keeps giving me problems. This map has many types of annotationView (for example cinemas, restaurants, theaters ....), each with their own image. When I passed from iOS6 to iOS5 I noticed that the annotationView do not behave the same  as before because the call of the delegate method to construct them is no longer the same. What can I do?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

     //.....
     //extraction of elements from the tables in a database

  for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ //extraction tables from database

    //......

    for (int i =0; i< number; i++) { //extraction elements from tables

        self.chinaTable =[self.mutableArray objectAtIndex:i];

         CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.chinaTable.latitudine, self.chinaTable.longitudine);

        AnnotationCustom *annotationIcone =[[AnnotationCustom alloc]initWithCoordinates:coord title:self.chinaTable.titolo subTitle:self.chinaTable.indirizzo];

        //.......

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.mapView.delegate=self; //the problem is here

   }

  }
```

The delegate method

```
  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
  <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
  {
        NSLog (@"the name of the table is %@", self.nomeTabella);
        // this NSLog you get only the name of the last open table

       //..........
       if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AnnotationCustom class]]){
          static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
       MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView*) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
       annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
      annotationView.annotation = annotation;
      AnnotationCustom *customAnnotation = (AnnotationCustom *)annotationView.annotation;

     //I create an annotation different depending on the name of the table of provenance

     if ([self.nomeTabella isEqualToString:@"Cinema"]){
            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_cinema.png"];

                customAnnotation.nomeTabella = self.nomeTabella;
                customAnnotation.ID = self.chinaTable.ID;
                customAnnotation.china = self.chinaTable;

           }else{
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_cinema.png"];
                customAnnotation.nomeTabella = self.nomeTabella;
                customAnnotation.ID = self.chinaTable.ID;
                customAnnotation.china=self.chinaTable;
            }

            //......

  }
```

The delegate method **`viewForAnnotation`** is no longer being called after the construction of each annotation, but is only called at the end of both cycles, accordingly `annotationView` on the map are only those of the last table in memory. Where can I get set i delegate methods to get the same result as before? ***`ViewForAnnotation`*** work fine in iPad 6.0 simulator but doesn't work in iPad simulator 5.1 and the code is the same

Comment: give some more code or make some sample code...so we can check your code at our end..

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised to hear that `viewForAnnotation` was only ever called after each construction. It's not the way it is documented and it is not the way it is used by anyone else. `viewForAnnotation` can and will be called at any point int your app. If the user scrolls the map so some annotations disappear it can be called when they scroll the map back and they annotations reappear. Or if the user switches to another view or app and then comes back.

You need to make *`viewForAnnotation`* check the `annotation` variable for some property that lets you determine how to draw that view. You can't rely on it being called in any particular order. There's plenty of sample code around that will show you how to implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol with your own class and you can add something to that class to tell you if the thing it represents is a cinema or restaurant or whatever, then you fetch the right image put it into the `MKAnnotationView` that `viewForAnnotation` wants as a return value.

Comment: I'd like to link to lmgtfy but SO is blocking it. Just google "MKAnnotation protocol example"

Answer (score 1):

`viewForAnnotation` isn't being called when you are running through your loops (i.e. as you add each `MKAnnotation`) because you are on the main `runLoop`. When your `viewDidLoad` finishes and a `runLoop` cycle occurs the `MKAnnotation`s (those on the current map location) will be drawn on the screen, thus calling out to your `delegate`. So while you are debugging and stepping through `viewDidLoad` it is perfectly normal that you are not seeing calls to the `delegate` methods.

A couple of things:

- You should be setting your delegate methods outside of the loops. so `self.locationManager.delegate` and `self.mapView.delegate` should be set before your `for` loops, not a million times inside your nested loops.
- You are reusing `i` as your `for...loop` variable. I'm hoping this is just caused by you removing business logic for posting here, and not in your actual code. It would explain why only your last set of annotations appears to be rendered.

Are you sure you aren't manipulating the `mapView.annotations` elsewhere in the nested `for...loops`? Check for `removeAnnotations` and `setAnnotations:` both could cause the annotations in the `mapView` to be different from what you'd expect.

Can you show how your `annotation` object is constructed? Another possibility is that you're accidentally mutating existing objects instead of creating new ones.

Comment: I have created the annotation in the second cycle. removeAnnotation and setAnnotation and I've never used

Answer (score 1):

your code seems ok to me. Actually I'm also developing an Iphone app using Maps and I'm doing it like you. Only one question, why are you using:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

is it to check if user is running an iPad or an iPhone?

Comment: I'm asking because I always use NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;